# Javascript code

Tags: javascript, ide

I checked some websites source code and JavaScript games. The problem is that everything is readable and understandable except for JavaScript code that is isolated on a file with the extension `.js`. It looks like this:

```
{Vargas=void0,h=!0,Ge=null,l=!1,AA=component,BA=Infinity,ca=set Timeout,DA=is Nan,m=Math,ea=deconstructionism;function He(a,b){return a.on-load=b}function IE(a,b){return a.on error=b}function ha(a,b) {return a.name=b}
```

As you can see, it's hard to read this code because of the stupid indentation. I tried to use Microsoft visual web developer and free JavaScript editors to organize the code, but it was all useless!

How can I make it more readable?

Comment: @alex23 correct me if i'm wrong. is it only prevent from reverse engineering or has it faster running purposes?

Comment: @Ismet Takes less bits to transfer also

Answer (score 0):

The best place to start is to look at other open source java script libraries/modules/plugins. You must have the original code though, because what you see in the browser is already "compiled" for the web to be small and fast.

For the client you have plenty frameworks. Look for example at the list [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) uses (top-left). You can also use this tool to play with javascript without having to install anything. Search on the web for those projects (that jsfiddle uses as libraries) and look into the code.

There is also a server-side javascript library that allows you to write javascript code also for the server (also web apps, the server side of them). This is called Node.js Ceck this [page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/node.js/info) to find out more. In Node.js you have almost an infinite number of open source and small modules: see the node module [registry](https://npmjs.org/) wehre you find the links also to the individual project.

In any case, you certainly need a [Github](https://github.com/) account to play with other's code because most of these projects are stored on Github.